# Inheritance and this keyword in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, reference, this

Hello guys I have **question related to 'this' keyword in Java**.
(1)
Lets say Computer extends from Machine and we have the current code:

```
public class Machine {
    private String name = "Machine";
    public void test()
    {
        System.out.println(this.name);
    }
    public void test2()
    {
        System.out.println(this);
    }
}

public class Computer extends Machine {
    public void test()
    {
        System.out.println(this);
    }
}

public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Machine c = new Computer();
        c.test();
        c.test2();
    }

}
```

**Its prints:**

```
Computer@1db9742
Computer@1db9742
```

It means the 'this' in Computer refers to Computer and this is I understood **but the 'this' in Machine also refers to Computer and this is what I didn't understand.**

How this happened and why..???
(2)
So if `Machine m = new Computer()` this is true?
[image]

So to all that answered me, i can understand that this is related to the `new` or what we say what our Type pointing for...?

Comment: What did you expect to happen?

Comment: To add to @AndyTurner's answer, I would recommend you go over inheritance in your textbooks for a complete treatise on this subject.

Comment: 'this' in Computer does not refer to 'Computer'. It refers to Computer@1db9742 (or "Machine c", the variable you declared), an object. Not the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keyword `this` refers to the current *object*, that is an *instance of a class*, not to a class itself. You have created a single object (with `new Computer()`), which is an instance of `Computer`. Since `Computer` is a subclass of `Machine`, it is also an instance of `Machine`, but the default `toString()` method will return a string containing the most precise type, in this case `Computer`.

Answer (score 0):

`this` is a pointer to the current object, and objects know what type they are.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access private variables from the class, you have to either create getter method or make the variable public, moreover this in System.out.println() calls toString() method, and if undefined, it prints something like that you have in results (type of object and location in memory).

Just create method in Machine class:

```
public String getName() {
   return name;
}
```

And in main method make add following:

```
System.out.println(c.getName());
```

Comment: I do not understand the purpose of your program, if you ask why this returns Computer not machine is because you explicitly declared your object to be computer right there:  Machine c = new Computer();

Answer (score 0):

Computer@1db9742 is just a name for your object. It is the same object, even if each method is defined in a different class.

"this" refers to the object, not to the class.

Answer (score 0):

`Computer` extends `Machine`, so `Computer` inherits all the methods of `Machine`, making them their own.

When you instantiate `Computer` you're running all of it's methods.

Answer (score 0):

`this` references the context that you are in. In your case, you are using it on the `Machine` and the `Computer` class.

To understand this, you need to first understand that the variable `Machine m`, is not the object itself, but it does reference to the object in the memory.

An then, you are calling from the same object, two different methods, one that is implemented on the objects class(`Computer`), and other that is implemented on its superclass(`Machine`).

Indifferently witch method is called, the object where you make the method call is the same, and the `this` keyword, will reference this same object, and then, the result of your test will be exactly the same object:

```
Computer@1db9742
Computer@1db9742
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the instanciated type that counts. Not the reference.
Take this example:

```
class Animal{
     void makeSound(){
           System.out.println("wut ? Don't know what to do :(");
     }
}
class Cat extends Animal{
     void makeSound(){
           System.out.println("Miaw !");
     }
}
```

when you create for example:

```
Animal a = new Cat();
```

You're actually creating a cat. And still, a Cat is always an animal ? (Am I right ? :D)
`a.makeSound()` will result in printing `Miaw !`. But !

```
Animal a= new Animal();
a.makeSound();
```

will result in printing : `wut ? Don't know what to do :(` . What's the sound of an animal after all ? You see ?

If someone asks you to bring an animal, you can always bring a cat. Right ?
Well, this is the case with methods asking for an Animal parameter:
take this function:

```
void doSomething(Animal param){
// some code
}
```

you can call it using a Cat object as a parameter:

```
//...
doSomething(new Cat());
//...
```

Etc.. (you can push the analogy.. for a wider level)

Java VM takes the responsibility to make a type resolution at run time to decide which method to call. And that's some of the sweetness of OOP.

Comment: Thanks, i understanded what you said, But depending on your concept, if every cat is animal, so if i do 'this' its okey to get an animal because cat is animal.

Comment: I see what you did there. JVM looks for the most restricted resolved type that still  provides the appropriate conditions for the current context of course.

Comment: I just want to add that after all, we'll have two situations: take the wider type (Animal) or the restricted one (Cat). Java (OOP in general) choose the practical perspective.